# Avoid Index Out Of Range error in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

In my UICollectionView I'm trying to return 1 item, if there's no data (in order to set an empty cell then). 
Here is the code:

```
    var movies = [Movies]()
```

---

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if movies.count == 0 {
        return 1
    } else {
        return movies.count
    }
}
```

I'm getting Fatal Error: Index Out Of Range. I know, that this way I'm trying to access an element under index[1] and that's impossible, because that element doesn't exist, that's the reason of this error.

But how can I avoid it in this case?

Comment: In this function you are saying... If I have no items... tell the collection view that I have 1 item. If you just return `movies.count` here your problem will go away. Also... your crash is not here... it is somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of you are returning **`1`** count in `numberOfItemsInSection` for empty array you need to check that your array is empty or not in `cellForItemAt` before subscripting with it.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if movies.isEmpty {
        //return your empty cell
    }
    else {
        //access array element and return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I was declaring my 2 cells and then in return I was like: return movies.count == 0 ? emptyCell : cell
I wonder why this doesn't work, but anyway.. Your case worked 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @EmmaVagradyan Welcome mate :)

Comment: @EmmaVagradyan just wondering, if you're using `return movies.count == 0 ? emptyCell : cell` then it should also work.

Comment: @KamaldeepsinghBhatia No don't use ternary operator at that place but you can use it at `numberOfItemsInSection` like this `return movies.isEmpty ? 1 : movies.count`

Comment: Yeah, that's the case
I clearly don't understand, why this doesn't work
Here's the initial code, I was using and was getting the **Index Out Of Range** error:
       `let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "movieCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! MovieCollectionCell

        let emptyCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "emptyCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! EmptyCollectionViewCell
        return movies.isEmpty ? emptyCell : cell`

Comment: @NiravD Not getting this 'don't use ternary operator at that place', I mean why can't we use ternary?

Comment: @KamaldeepsinghBhatia because for that you need to check array is not empty twice once to access array element from it and after that returning cell that is useless

Comment: oh, Yes... Thanks @NiravD

Comment: @KamaldeepsinghBhatia Welcome mate :)